# Managing multiple Ether addresses in one contract?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, internal-transactions, wallet-transfer

Although I have a background in Bitcoin (creating the [WLOX](http://github.com/mbassan/wlox) exchange platform), I am completely new to Ethereum.

I am trying to find a way to manage multiple accounts/addresses as a pool to 
(1) be able to manage hot/cold storage for my application and 
(2) avoid having to manage every account/address in the wallet individually.

If there is a way to transfer funds between accounts internally (without the blockchain) it would work for me too.

I have read that smart contracts are potentially a way to do this, but I'm open to any solution.

Can anybody direct me to an existing example, or tell me how it can be done?

I realize this is a very general question, but I'm against the clock, so I might as well try my luck.

Comment: I think your question is too open ended. Some things can be done, for example there are contracts that are used as a sort of decentralized exchange, there are multisig wallet, with daily limits. But I'd say you what you want to do is something more complex and it will require carefull planification and testing.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation looking for a way to manage differents wallets to receive the users payments but I don't want to:
1- Make the user call a smart contrac, I want to make as easiest possible. So I want the user to make an eth transaction only to a wallet.
2- have all the funds distributed over many wallets.
And I want to offer a wallet for each user, with the idea to identify each transaction with only one user. Any idea?